# crashing at presentScene(GameScene())

Tags: swift, xcode6, sprite-kit

I'm building a game in which characters fall from the top, as your character shoots up from the bottom.
I have a restart button in the top corner, that I'm trying to program to restart the scene, as it's a single scene game.

I have two timers running, one for the bullets and one for spawning the falling characters.

This is what I have happening when the restart button is clicked

```
        if button.containsPoint(location)
        {
            Timer.invalidate()
            RepubTimer.invalidate()
            self.view?.presentScene(GameScene())

            println("tapped!")
        }
```

when I click the restart button in the game, for about a half second, it shows the GameScene blown up massively. The whole screen is just the color of my main character. Then it crashes. I thought invalidating the timers would work but it hasnt.

Comment: How many times do you get the "tapped!" log

Comment: Also, it's kind of weird that you're presenting a new scene that's the same object when you are already in a GameScene. Why don't you just make a method that configures a new game and call that method instead of presenting a new scene? Unless you need the transition I guess.

Comment: Could you paste the init method for your scene? And `didMoveToViw:`? I suspect your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I confirm that a scene can present another instance of its class. problem should be somewhere else.